# .HTACCESS is Creating Unnecessary 301 Redirect Chain - How to Remove?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**My Stack:**

- LAMP
- Apache/2.4.41

**Background Information:**

I recently launched a new website for a client. During the re-design process we decided to:

- Switch to sitewide HTTPS
- Remove the .php extension from the URLs
- Switch to a CMS

**Example of OLD URL:**
`http://www.example.com/courses/acme-course.php`

**Example of NEW URL:**
`https://www.example.com/courses/acme-course`

**My Issue:**

An unnecessary additional 301 Redirect is occurring when a user navigates to one of the OLD URLs.

I do not understand why the additional 301 redirect is being created and not sending the user directly to the correct destination URL using a single 301 redirect.

**Interesting Observation:**

The unnecessary additional 301 Redirect does not occur when I use the OLD URL with HTTPS instead of HTTP.

**Example:**
`https://www.example.com/courses/acme-course.php`
_

Using the above URL will correctly do a single 301 Redirect to the correct destination URL of: `https://www.example.com/courses/acme-course`

**Here's an Example of a 301 Redirect Chain:**

*Original Request URL:*

`http://www.example.com/courses/acme-course.php`

*1ST 301 Redirect (Unnecessary):*

**FROM:**

`http://www.example.com/courses/acme-course.php`

**TO:**

`https://www.example.com/index.php?url=courses/acme-course.php`

*2ND 301 Redirect (Correct Final Destination URL):*

**FROM:**

`https://www.example.com/index.php?url=courses/acme-course.php`

**TO:**

`https://www.example.com/courses/acme-course`

**My .htaccess code:**

```
# (1) General Settings
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

# (2) Force WWW
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=::1
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:PROTO}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# (3) Force HTTPS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# (4) URL Routing for CMS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
    RewriteRule ^ - [env=proto:https]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ - [env=proto:http]

    ## Check if file/directory exists
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    ## Route all other URLs to index.php/URL
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you have any intention of implementing HSTS in the future?

Comment: @MrWhite Yes, I am familiar with and intend on implementing HSTS in the future, AFTER I've seen (i) the old HTTP URLs get pushed out of Google Index and (ii) confirm that the new HTTPS URLs have fully-resolved and are indexed.

Comment: @MrWhite If I reorder the rules/conditions, does my placement of **Options +FollowSymlinks** stay the same?

Comment: It doesn't much matter. I've addressed the placement of these directives in more detail in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two main issues....

1. Your directives are in the wrong order in the `.htaccess` file. Your HTTP to HTTPS and `www` canonical redirects need to go *before* your front-controller that routes the URL to your CMS. Hence the incorrect external redirect to `/index.php?url=courses/acme-course.php` - exposing your internal CMS URL structure.

2. The removal of `.php` is not actually being performed by your `.htaccess` directives?! I assume this must be being done by your application/CMS logic? Consequently, this will *always* result in a second redirect (since `.htaccess` is redirecting to HTTPS on the same URL-path). You need to do something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file to remove the `.php` extension.

   ```
   RewriteRule (.+)\.php$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
   ```

> **UPDATE:** If I reorder the rules/conditions, does my placement of Options +FollowSymlinks stay the same?

It doesn't really matter *where* the `Options` directive occurs. However, it is logical (from a readability standpoint) to have it near the top. (Apache directives don't necessarily execute in the order they appear in the config file, as each module works independently.)

Assuming you are hand-coding your `.htaccess` file then it can be tidied up...

1. There is no need for the (multiple) `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrappers. Is mod_rewrite optional? Is your site be ported to multiple servers where mod_rewrite is not enabled?
2. There is no need for multiple `RewriteEngine` directives. The *last* instance actually *wins* and controls the entire file.

   Multiple `<IfModule>` blocks and `RewriteEngine` are typical of systems that are automatically edited by code and/or designed to function unedited on multiple servers.

So, your `.htaccess` file should be rewritten like this in this order:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

# Enable the rewrite engine...   
RewriteEngine On

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Forcing `https://`                                                       |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Redirect to HTTPS on the "same host" (requirement for HSTS)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Forcing `www`                                                          |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=::1
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | URL Routing for CMS                                              |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# (3)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^ - [env=proto:https]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ - [env=proto:http]
   
# (4) - Check if physical file exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  

# (5) - Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Additional Notes:

- The `PROTO` environment variable contains whatever protocol is being requested. With the order of the redirects this is now always going to be HTTPS. The reason for this variable at all is so the CMS can redirect to HTTP if HTTP is accessed, or HTTPS if HTTPS is accessed. If you are forcing HTTPS then it doesn't really apply. (Although this env var may still be used by your application.)
- Rarely should you use the `NC` flag on a negated condition. Hence why I removed it from the condition `!^www\.`. You want it to redirect when the host does not start with `www.` - all lowercase. With the `NC` flag it will fail to redirect `WwW.` - although this would be very rare anyway.
- I've removed the unnecessary check for HTTPS on the www canonical redirect.
- The `PT` flag on the last `RewriteRule` is not required in `.htaccess`. In `.htaccess` this is the default behaviour (pass through).
- You will need to clear your browser cache before testing, as the erroneous 301 redirects will likely have been cached by the browser. It is a good idea to test with 302 (temporary) redirects for this reason.

Comment: #2:  No, I currently don't have anything that 'removes' the .php extension. If the requested URI is found in my url_redirects table, it redirects the user to the new destination URL.

Example:  courses/acme-course.php > courses/acme-course

Comment: Ok, so your "url_redirects table" is effectively your `.php` removal script then it would seem? A small redirect "chain" of two redirects (which you can't avoid if you are performing one redirect in `.htaccess` and a second in your application) is not necessarily a bad thing. And if you are planning to implement HSTS (preload list) then this is actually becomes a requirement (at least to redirect HTTP to HTTPS on the same hostname).

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Your **Additional Notes** section really helped explain and help me understand. After reviewing your updated code, do I really need the following?
`
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on

RewriteRule ^ - [env=proto:https]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

RewriteRule ^ - [env=proto:http]

`

Comment: "do I really need the following?" - As mentioned above, only if your application uses it. Some CMS use an environment variable like this to construct absolute URLs internally. Whether your CMS uses this I couldn't say.